# What is this set of infinite prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading a book and the books splits $\mathbb{N}$ into infinitely many infinite subsets $\{B_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

It defines these $B_{n}$s as:
[image]

How are these sets infinite? isn't $B_{1}=\{2\}$, $B_{2}=\{3\}$ etc? and what is that $i$?

Comment: $B_1 = \{2, 4, 8, 16...\}, B_2=\{3, 9, 27, 81,...\}$ etc

Comment: $B_{n}$ is the set of the powers of $p_{n}$. $B_{1}=\{2,4,8,...\}$.

Comment: @Gio oooh i read it like an index ‍♂️ since the exercise right above used $i$ as an index, thank you! if you put it as an answer i will give you the best answer

Answer (score 0):

$\{p_n^i\,:\, i>0\}$ is another notation for the set $\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, \exists i>0,\, x=p_n^i\}$. Or, if you want to spell out the implicit hypothesis, $\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, \exists i\in\Bbb N,\, (i>0\land p_n^i=x)\}$